# Powershell - after inputting to stdin capturing stdout/stderr no longer works

Tags: powershell, process, stdout, stderr, plink

In a pretty restricted environment I'm basically only allowed to use Powershell + Plink if I want to automate some tasks.

I want to create a function that:

- shows the output as it arrives if required
- captures all output (stdout and stderr) to make it available later for further parsing or logging to console/file/whatever
- inputs a password automatically

Unfortunately after the line where I input the password output capture stops. It used to work when I was only capturing stdout. After capturing stderr as well, no more luck.

The code:

```
function BaseRun {
    param ($command, $arguments, $output = "Console")

    $procInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $procInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    $procInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
    $procInfo.RedirectStandardInput = $true
    $procInfo.FileName = $command
    $procInfo.Arguments = $arguments
    $procInfo.UseShellExecute = $false

    $process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $process.StartInfo = $procInfo
    [void]$process.Start()

    $outputStream = $process.StandardOutput
    $errorStream = $process.StandardError
    $inputStream = $process.StandardInput

    $outputBuffer = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder

    Start-Sleep -m 2000
    $inputStream.Write("${env:password}`n")

    while (-not $process.HasExited) {
        do {
            $outputLine = $outputStream.ReadLine()
            $errorLine = $errorStream.ReadLine()
            [void]$outputBuffer.Append("$outputLine`n")

            if (($output -eq "All") -or ($output -eq "Console")) {
                Write-Host "$outputLine"
                Write-Host "$errorLine"
            }
        } while (($outputLine -ne $null) -and ($errorLine -ne $null))
    }

    return $outputBuffer.ToString()
}
```

Comment: I don't have a ready-to-use solution but IIRC the problem is caused by the fact you're doing it synchronously. So I think you need to move `$inputStream.Write` into a new thread/RunSpace/whatever. Or do the output collection via `Register-ObjectEvent $Process OutputDataReceived ......`

Comment: Damn, I hoped I could avoid the whole asynchronous shebang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @w0xx0m's and @Martin Prikryl's help I managed to make this working solution:

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $process `
    -EventName OutputDataReceived -SourceIdentifier processOutputDataReceived `
    -Action {
    $data = $EventArgs.data
    if($data -ne $null) { Write-Host $data }
} | Out-Null

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $process `
    -EventName ErrorDataReceived -SourceIdentifier processErrorDataReceived `
    -Action {
    $data = $EventArgs.data
    if($data -ne $null) { Write-Host $data }
} | Out-Null

[void]$process.Start()
$process.BeginOutputReadLine()
$process.BeginErrorReadLine()

$inputStream = $process.StandardInput

Start-Sleep -m 2000
$inputStream.Write("${env:password}`n")

$process.WaitForExit()

Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier processOutputDataReceived
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier processErrorDataReceived

$inputStream.Close()
```

For brevity I've removed the process launch section (it's the same as the one from above) and the data processing (in the example I just Write-Host it).

Answer (score 1):

When you are reading both stdout and stderr, you cannot not use the `ReadLine`.

- First, if there's only stderr output and no stdout, the `$outputStream.ReadLine()` never returns and you never get to the `$errorStream.ReadLine()`.
- A bigger problem is, that there's only a limited buffer in Windows for the outputs. So, when there's a lot of stderr before a complete stdout line is produced, the stderr buffer fills up and the applications (Plink) stops on the next attempt to write to stderr, waiting for the stderr buffer to be consumed. What it never does, as you keep waiting on a wrong stdout buffer. A deadlock.

You have to use a simple `Read` and never synchronously wait, when there's no output available.

Comment: So, basically, I have to start using Read() everywhere. The code I was using previously had a break when the output was null. But if I do that the loop will skip reading stderr, I think.

Comment: Yes. I think you do not need those two nested loops. Just keep the outer `while (-not $process.HasExited)`.